# Distributing a subtree into different LDAP servers

Tags: openldap

I'm trying to create a distributed OpenLDAP server where everything under a subtree is split into different servers.

For example, I have ou=users,dc=ldap. I have users under it in a flat structure, no hierarchy, just a plain list. I want to split the entries under ou=users,dc=ldap into different servers. How do I do that?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve with multiple servers? Because as it stands what you're trying to do doesn't make much sense...

Comment: What criteria would you use when deciding which server a chunk of this flat structure is on? Question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Well the list of users reaches up to millions. I wanted them split. As for the criteria, I haven't thought of that yet. Probably some attribute of the entry.

Answer (score 2):

With *LDAP referrals*. What is that? When a client connects to a LDAP server that does not contain the needed information, the server will tell the client to ask from some other server.

OpenLDAP fully supports this on the server-side and the admin guide has a section called [Constructing a Distributed Directory Service](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/referrals.html).

Comment: Although referrals work on splitting a branch off a directory tree and @Carlo has a flat structure...

Comment: Nevertheless there is no answer that doesn't require the OP to define further subtrees. It could also be accomplished via the LDAP back end.

Comment: I see. I guess I have no choice but to create a hierarchy for the users. I'm also curious about how to solve this via the LDAP back end. How do I do that?